# Does the jupiter ipynb version file differ?

Tags: python, markdown, jupyter

I have a question.Jupyter ipynb files vary on the system, does anyone know why?I have two ipynb files on my hand, why are they different?
I show in the example below.As you can see in the examples below, one starts in the (worksheets) block and the other starts in the (cells) block. I wonder why

ipynb - 1 (worksheets)

```
"worksheets": [
  {
   "cells": [
    {
     "cell_type": "markdown", 
     "source": "# Funciones suaves con segunda derivada enloquecida\n\nUn 
    },
```

ipynb - 2 (cells)

```
{
 "cells": [
  {
   "cell_type": "markdown",
   "metadata": {
    "slideshow": {
     "slide_type": "slide"
    }
   },
```